# How can I use MongoDB to find all documents which have a field, regardless of the value of that field?

Tags: mongodb

For example, I have collection with documents, where documents can have field "url" (but most of them doesn't).
How can I find all documents, which have field "url" (regardless of value of this field)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mongodb Query To select records having a given key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4582354/mongodb-query-to-select-records-having-a-given-key)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

To find if a key/field exists in your document use the [$exists](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%24exists) operator.

Via the MongoDB shell ...

```
> db.things.find( { url : { $exists : true } } );
```

Answer (score 1):

> db.things.find( { url : { $exists : true } }, {url:1, _id:1});

if you changed you mind and you want to display just the url without the _id you have to change the value of the _id key to 0.