# Mongodb Query To select records having a given key

Tags: mongodb

The records in my database are

```
{"_id":"1","fn":"sagar","ln":"Varpe"}

{"_id":"1","fn":"sag","score":"10"}

{"_id":"1","ln":"ln1","score":"10"}

{"_id":"1","ln":"ln2"}
```

I need to design a MongoDB query to find all records that have a given key.

For example, if I pass `ln` as a parameter to the query it shuold return all records in which `ln`is a key.  The results would be

```
{"_id":"1","fn":"sagar","ln":"Varpe"}

{"_id":"1","ln":"ln1","score":"10"}

{"_id":"1","ln":"ln2"}
```

Answer (score 132, accepted):

To find if a key/field exists in your document use the [$exists](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%24exists) operator.

Via the MongoDB shell ...

```
db.things.find( { ln : { $exists : true } } );
```

Comment: in PyMongo: `connection['db']['collection'].find({"key":{'$exists': True}})`

Answer (score 11):

I had the same problem and

```
db.coll.find({"mykey":{'$exists': 1}})
```

worked for me

Comment: This does indeed work, but `{'$exists': 'true'}` will always be more obvious to other code readers than `{'$exists': 1}`. Thanks for pointing this out though!

Answer (score 4):

```
db.collection.find({ ln: { $exists: true} });
```

The $size operator matches any array with the number of elements specified by the argument. For example:

```
db.collection.find({ ln: { $exists: true, $size: 0 } });
```

$size does not accept ranges of values. To select documents based on fields with different numbers of elements, create a counter field that you increment when you add elements to a field.