# How do I find documents containing a certain key?

Tags: mongodb

I have a MongoDB database where some documents have keys that others don't. For example, one document might have `{ "_id": "1", "country": "USA", "state": "FL" }`
and another might have `{ "_id": "2", "country": "Mexico", "state" : "Veracruz" }`, and yet another might have `{ "_id: "3", "country": "Jamaica", "parish":"St. Elizabeth"}` . How do I run a query to find only documents that contain a 'state' key?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mongodb Query To select records having a given key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4582354/mongodb-query-to-select-records-having-a-given-key)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you need is the [`$exists`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/) operator:

```js
db.collection.find({state:{$exists:true}})
```

Comment: @anyaelise, no problem.  if your question is answered, please feel free to [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) the answer.